What properties must $\phi(x)$ in $\{x|\phi(x)\}$ have in order not to bring a paradox?
Consider the set-builder notation:
$\{x|\phi(x)\}$
Sometimes it leads to Russell's paradox, like:
$R=\{x|x\notin x\}$
Sometimes it doesn't, like:
$\emptyset =\{x|x\neq x\}$
I wonder what properties $\phi(x)$ must have in order not to bring a paradox.

By that do you just mean that it defines a set?

@AsafKaragila I use the set-builder notation here to mean $A={x|\phi(x)}\leftrightarrow \forall x(x \in  A\leftrightarrow \phi(x) )$

Worth a read.

Not a reply to what I wrote, @William.

@AsafKaragila Did you mean "${x|\phi(x)}$ defines a set"? Can you please rewrite what is in the quotation marks into an FOL formula? I use it just as abbreviation for FOL formulas. I know sometimes it defines a set, sometimes it does not. I don't care if it is a set but when it leads to a paradox and when not.

I assume that your question can be reformulated as follows:
Which instances of the unrestricted comprehension ($\mathsf{UC}$) could be consistently added to the classical predicate logic ($\mathsf{Cl\forall}$) with the axiom of extensionality ($\mathsf{ext}$)?
There are some straightforward examples like Quine's New Foundations, which uses only so-called stratified formulas (in the axiom of comprehension), or the positive set theory, which uses only formulas without $\neg$ and $\rightarrow$.
But if you ask generally as to which instances of the $\mathsf{UC}$ are completely unproblematic (meaning that they could be added to any consistent extension of $\mathsf{Cl\forall{+}ext}$ by $\mathsf{UC}$-instances and preserve consistency), then the answer would be: none. The reason being that we can always construct a consistent theory, which becomes inconsistent by asserting the existence of some concrete set $A$. Let me show how:
Let us assume that asserting the existence of the set $A$ is unproblematic*. Now, consider the theory, which extends the $\mathsf{Cl\forall{+}ext}$ by the following instance:
$B = \{x|\exists A \rightarrow x\notin x\}$
Such theory ($\mathsf{Cl\forall{+}ext}{+}\exists B$) is consistent, since it has a model -- e.g. single Quine's atom**. But if you add to the theory the assertion that $A$ exists (the theory $\mathsf{Cl\forall{+}ext}{+}\exists B{+}\exists A$), then it becomes inconsistent, since $B$ becomes the Russell's set. So $A$ is not unproblematic.
*) There are actually some restriction on the choice of $A$. One such restriction would be that $A$ is not the universal set $\{x|x=x\}$. These restrictions could be circumvented by more elaborate example of the set $B$.
**) This is not entirely precise, it could be that $A$ is e.g. the universal set, and then $\mathsf{Cl\forall{+}ext}{+}\exists B$ would already be inconsistent.
Let me know if I should elaborate more.

But what is the difefrence between your example with set $B$ and the usual Separation: $B = { x \in A \mid \varphi(x) }$ ?

@MauroALLEGRANZA that the elements $x$ can be taken outside the scope of $A$

Not clear... If $A$ is an "unproblematic" set whatever whose only requirement is that exists, then $\exists A$ is true and thus formula $\exists A \to x \notin x$ simply amounts to $x \notin x$.

@MauroALLEGRANZA yes, my point was that $\mathsf{Cl\forall{+}ext}{+}\exists B$ is consistent (if $A$ is not equivalent to the universal set) but $\mathsf{Cl\forall{+}ext}{+}\exists B{+}\exists A$ is not consistent
